# Erro no Commit do Git

Tags: git

Estou com o Windows, instalei o git, fiz o config com os dados de user e email, porém acontece que, quando vou fazer um commit em algum repositório local criado, ele me pede a identificação de config (user.mail).

O que é muito estranho, pois se dou config --list ele mostra os dados que eu entrei inicialmente e se abro o arquivo .config também está lá.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obs: Eu consigo adicionar(add) no stage porém gravar(commit) não!

[image: Retorno do comando]

Comment: Você instalou o tortoisegit? Ou apenas o git de linha de comando? Ou os dois?

Comment: Apenas o git! Mas de qualquer forma alguém pelo menos faz ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Se você colocar o comando `git config --get --global user.email`, o que ele retorna?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Retorna o e-mail configurado como global!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que parece ser o erro é que você configurou `user.mail` e não `user.email`.
Sendo assim o que você deve fazer para configurar o email é a seguinte linha de comando:

```
git config --global user.email seuemail@dominio.com.br
```

E quando realizar o próximo commit, ele não solicitará que insira os dados de e-mail para config.